# Redux State Mutation When Dispatch an Action

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

I have a table like

[image]

When you edit the quantity using this onChange

```
onChange={this.handleInputChange.bind(null, cellInfo)}
```

I run the below code

```
handleInputChange = (cellInfo, event) => {
    let data = { ...this.props.Data };
    data[cellInfo.index][cellInfo.column.id] = parseInt(event.target.value);
    this.props.APISummaryData(data);
  };
```

Goal being first get the data in the store, then reflect the value you changed and then update it with action `this.props.APISummaryData(data);` and `this.props.APISummaryData({ ...data });` both give same State mutation error.

Here's the reducer

```
case types.API_SUMMARY_DATA:
    return {
        ...state,
        Summary: {
            ...state.Summary,
            Data: action.Summary
    }
};
```

If I manually dispatch an action within Redux inside DevTools doing

```
{
  type: 'API_SUMMARY_DATA',
  Summary: [
    {
      cusip: '019I',
      quantity: 55,
    }
  ]
}
```

This is the action

```
export const APISummaryData = Summary => ({ type: types.API_SUMMARY_DATA, Summary });
```

I don't get any error and data gets updated. I am so puzzled where in this scheme I mutate the state?

Note: it is possible I am not sharing some code that's important to take a look here, so please let me know and I'll share it.

exact error
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you're using `configureStore()` from Redux Starter Kit, which sets up a mutation checking middleware by default.  Good!  This means that the mutation checker is doing its job correctly.

These lines right here are mutating:

```js
    let data = { ...this.props.Data };
    data[cellInfo.index][cellInfo.column.id] = parseInt(event.target.value);
```

That's because the `{...}` object spread operator does a *shallow* copy, not a deep copy.  [This is a very common mistake](https://redux.js.org/recipes/structuring-reducers/immutable-update-patterns#common-mistake-2-only-making-a-shallow-copy-of-one-level).

I personally would recommend dispatching an action that looks like:

`{type: "API_SUMMARY_DATA", payload: {index, columnId, inputValue}}`

and then use the reducer to do all the updating.

Also, if you are using Redux Starter Kit, [you can use our `createReducer()` function to write "mutative" code in the reducer that actually does immutable updates](https://redux-starter-kit.js.org/api/createreducer).

Comment: Thank you @markerikson, how would I do the reducer? do I need to go level by level in until I reach what I need to update?

Comment: [***If*** you are using `createReducer()`](https://redux-starter-kit.js.org/usage/usage-guide#simplifying-reducers-with-createreducer), you could actually use basically that same "mutative" line of code inside the reducer and it would be safe: `state[index][columnId] = inputValue`.  But, please read the docs on `createReducer()` carefully to understand how it works.

Comment: Wow! This createReducer cut the reducer line of code over less than half! Before 47 lines now 22.. Plus makes it much easier to update things!

Comment: Yep, that's the idea! :)